# How to run AIA without manual change in google account settings?

Tags: android, google-oauth, progressive-web-apps, android-instant-apps

> You may have to turn instant apps on in your device settings (Settings
>   -> Google -> Instant Apps -> [Toggle on])

1: Is there any way to run the AIA **without manual work** for the user? Like the whole point for AIA is to improve customer experience/engagement.

2: Can I turn on that setting by using oauth2.0? My purpose is to reduce the ***number of steps*** for the end user to use the app without installing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't skip that part because it's stated in [Run instant apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/first-instant-app):

> Step 3. In the system's Settings menu, go to Google > Instant Apps
>   and opt into Android Instant Apps.

Comment: If a user can turn on settings manually, then he can install the whole app. Then whats the point to build an instant app in the first place? o.O

Comment: I think AIA are still early enough that Google wants more usage and data before enabling them by default.